# Log4j Multithreading in Solaris

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, solaris

I have a multithreaded application and im using log4j for the logging. When i test my application on my windows 7/intel laptop, it works just fine. But when i deploy the same application to the production server(solaris/sparc), it works for 10 minutes then starts to slow down(very slow). I used profiler to see the threads state. There were a lot of threads blocked because of the log4j operations in the thread dump. Im also using async appender but coulnd't manage to get any successful result. Any guess?

Here are some dump:

```
"pool-7-thread-105" - Thread t@22939
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
    - waiting to lock <794f2dae> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger) owned by "pool-7-thread-112" t@22946
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)

"pool-7-thread-112" - Thread t@22946
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    - locked <5fcbc329> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
    - locked <19e9d0c5> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    - locked <3680c465> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    - locked <3fddded7> (a org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    - locked <794f2dae> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
```

Also log4j.xml - version 1.2.17

```
<appender name="scripts" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <param name="file" value="log/script.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%-6p[%-d{ISO8601}] [%t] %m (%F:%L) %n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-6p[%-d{ISO8601}] [%t] %m (%F:%L) %n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="5000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="scripts"/>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
</root>
```

Comment: How much stuff are you logging? What is the logging going to? And what version of log4j are you using?

Comment: I have 200 threads logging at the same time. I don't know that it is too much or not but i know that this is working well on windows.

Comment: You should just use fewer threads. You don't have 200 CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

So the threads that are trying to log are blocked. Why? Because a logging thread is currently blocked in `java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)`. That strongly suggests that the thing the logging is going to (a file or whatever) cannot keep up with the amount of logging being done.

The way to troubleshoot this is to start with looking at where your logging is going. If it's going to a file, is that file on a fast, local filesystem? Is disk I/O an issue?

You may wish to use a logging scheme that doesn't block on I/O. It doesn't have to -- other threads can log to an internal queue while a thread is doing disk I/O. However, if the logging rate exceeds the I/O rate, eventually you have to stop logging from building up in memory somehow, and that requires either blocking threads or throwing log entries away. That said, this shouldn't be an issue unless you are either logging way too much, have a serious I/O performance issue (like logging over NFS on a crowded network), or have file buffering disabled somehow.

Comment: Good points. I will ask the system guys about the disk performance and the solaris file buffering. By the way, i don't think that i am doing a lot of logging. Since the solaris operating systems also having cpu rate 100% every 10 seconds(windows never goes up 20%) i am starting to think that this is a platform issue. Maybe i should try turning off immediateFlush.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the stack dump, something is calling flush() ... so that is going to negate a lot of the "goodness" of using BufferedOutputStream. If you can figure out how to avoid the flushes the throughput will improve.

David Schwartz comments thus:

> Windows is notorious for not really honoring file flushes as a way to improve its performance. Solaris and Linux really do full flushes. This might help explain the platform-dependent performance difference.

(I didn't know that.  And yes it would.)

> Turning off [immediateFlush](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html#immediateFlush) in the WriterAppender might help

Excellent advice.

Comment: Nice catch. Windows is notorious for not really honoring file flushes as a way to improve its performance. Solaris and Linux really do full flushes. This might help explain the platform-dependent performance difference. Turning off [immediateFlush](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html#immediateFlush) in the `WriterAppender` might help. (You shouldn't have to though. There's still something else going on.)